# git save history of resolved merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

In our repository, we have two branches that have been diverging for some time now and I need to merge them back together. There will obviously be lots of conflicts, hopefully minor...

```
(foo )$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: some_commit1
Applying: some_commit2
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging some_file.xyz
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in some_file.xyz
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 some_commit2

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

I would like to somehow save the conflicts that need to be resolved and my resolutions of them, so that I could share them with the team as a code review so that we could ensure that everything was done correctly in the merge. Is there a good way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [git rerere](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere). You may also want to see the SO question [Sharing rerere cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566023/sharing-rerere-cache).

After you resolve merge conflicts but before you commit your resolution, `git rerere diff` will show you the resolution that will be recorded. Resolutions that have been committed are stored in .git/rr-cache